# Get last 7 days data from controller laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to create a function that get the last seven days date and count the common date.

Something like this

```
column1     column2
10/28/2020      5
10/27/2020      0
10/26/2020      6
10/25/2020      2
10/24/2020      1
10/23/2020      0
10/22/2020      2
```

but when getting the date of last seven days the date getting off.
[image]

This is the code:

```
        $today = Carbon::today();
        $date_array = array();
        $date_count = array();

        $i = 0;
        while ($i < 7) {
            array_push( $date_array, $today->subDays($i)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') );
            $i++;
        }

        if(! empty( $date_array ) ){
            foreach($date_array as $date){
                $date_count = CampaignHistory::where( 'created_at', '>', $date )->get()->count();
            }
        }

        echo json_encode($date_array );
```

Comment: you can't use `where` with an array. In this case you don't really need to you just need a single date of 7 days ago.

Comment: if i get a single date of 7 days ago like this $date = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(30);

$users = User::where('created_at', '>=', $date)->get(); It unable to show when there is 0 when on 28/10/2020 for example

Comment: try this code.
while ($i < 7) {
             $new_date = $today;
            array_push( $date_array, $new_date->subDays($i)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') );
            $i++;
        }. 
@LeviLooi

Comment: @GauravGupta this gets the same date that i get

Comment: @LeviLooi join this https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223689/discussion-between-suleman-ahmad-and-ala-ben-aicha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In place of assigning today in start put it under the loop so that every time it initializes again to the current date when you sub day for `$today` it becomes
`$today = $day-$i;`

```
    $date_array = array();
    $date_count = array();

    $i = 0;
    while ($i < 7) {
        $today = Carbon::today();
        array_push( $date_array, $today->subDays($i)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') );
        $i++;
    }

    if(! empty( $date_array ) ){
        foreach($date_array as $date){
            $date_count = CampaignHistory::where( 'created_at', '>', $date )->get()->count();
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($date_array );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(! empty( $date_array ) ) {
    foreach($date_array as $date){
      $date_count = CampaignHistory::whereDate( 'created_at', '=', $date )->count();
    }
 }
```

Comment: thks for replying but the main problem is the date that produced from last 7 days is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
    while ($i < 7) {
        $today = Carbon::today();
        array_push( $date_array, $today->subDays($i)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') );
        $i++;
    }
```

Result:

```
array(7) {
  [0] =>
  string(19) "2020-10-28 00:00:00"
  [1] =>
  string(19) "2020-10-27 00:00:00"
  [2] =>
  string(19) "2020-10-26 00:00:00"
  [3] =>
  string(19) "2020-10-25 00:00:00"
  [4] =>
  string(19) "2020-10-24 00:00:00"
  [5] =>
  string(19) "2020-10-23 00:00:00"
  [6] =>
  string(19) "2020-10-22 00:00:00"
}
```